# Unity VideoPlayer not rendering Video correctly to Texture

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, video-streaming

I'm trying to use a VideoPlayer component, with a URL source and a RenderTexture as the target, to show a video in my Unity mobile game. The video is loaded and starts playing, however the resulting texture is only 1 color. The color does change every frame to something matching what the video would look like that frame, but it's just the 1 color. Audio is working fine. On the VideoPlayer component, the Aspect Ratio is set to "Fit Inside", but I have tried all options here with the same result. As for the RenderTexture, it's set to the same resolution as the input video, and the Color Format is set to RGB565 (which both Android and iOS should support according to SystemInfo.SupportRenderTextureFormat()). I'm all out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: A workaround could be using "material override" instead of rendering to a texture. This doesn't work though if you want to use the texture specifically instead of only showing the video on a material, plus the fact that Material Override doesn't support objects with multiple renderers/materials. Not really a fix, but a workaround for those who find this question before a solution has been found.

Comment: Have you tried another video? Just make sure that your video is not the issue

Comment: Yes I have tried different video's and gotten the same result.

Comment: Maybe check the scale of your objects and check the resolution again (this really sounds like it just displays one pixel). Finally, try changing the material. I once had trouble with render textures and I solved it by using a shader that support writing to stencil buffer

Comment: Ok. The title says that you want to render the video to a Texture. I thin you are doing something wrong but all you really want to do is render the video to Texture2D? Why? I need to know what you do with that Texture and how you use it

Comment: @Programmer he means a render texture and he uses is as reference in the videoplayer component which needs it to render the video into.

Comment: @Programmer I want to use a video as the texture on a 3D object. To achieve this, I'm trying to use a "VideoPlayer" component, and a "RenderTexture" which is a texture-type in Unity. The result I should be getting is that whereever I use the RenderTexture instead of a normal texture, I get the video instead of a normal texture.

Comment: @Riv what is the object you are trying to play the video on (i.e. 3D cube, 2D `RawImage`, `Canvas`, etc)? If it's 3D, try adding a `Plane` and displaying it on that. I had issues with an imported model doing the exact same thing you're describing, but adding a `Plane` and making it the same size will play it properly (not a fix, but a slightly better workaround, I think).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this myself and fixed it.
In the Raw Image, search UV Rect and set its W and H to 1. I had changed that, which made it only sample 1 pixel.