# Is there a way to stretch a RenderTexture playing on a plane with a VideoPlayer in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having issues with a `VideoPlayer` targeting a `RenderTexture` and displaying on a plane, and getting confused. In case it matters, I'm using Unity 2018.2.11f1 and Vuforia to place the video screen in AR (though this shouldn't matter, to my knowledge, as I'm just trying to play a video in a 3D world, regardless of AR/VR). I started off using [the YouTube Unity tutorial on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KG2aq_CY7pU) but moved into doing it in a script for my purposes.

In the [Unity documentation for the `VideoPlayer` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html), it says of the property `Aspect Ratio`:

> The aspect ratio of the images that fill the **Camera Near Plane**, **Camera Far Plane** or **Render Texture** when the corresponding **Render Mode** is used.

And for the `Stretch` value of that property:

> Scale both horizontally or vertically to fit the destination rectangle. The source aspect ratio is not preserved.

My understanding of this is that these settings on the `VideoPlayer`:

[image: Screen capture of VideoPlayer settings]

would cause the `RenderTexture` to stretch to fill the size of the plane it is rendering on... but instead I am getting this (ignore the washed-out colours, it's lighting that I haven't fixed):

[image: Screen capture of plane displaying video]

which is obviously the result of the property `Wrap Mode` being "Clamp" on the `RenderTexture`. I am setting things up through code, like this:

```
var Screen = this.gameObject.AddComponent<Renderer>();
var VideoRenderer = Screen.gameObject.AddComponent<Renderer>();
var VideoTexture = new RenderTexture((int)Clip.width, (int)Clip.height, 0);

VideoTexture.useDynamicScale = true;
VideoTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;

Screen.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.RenderTexture;
Screen.aspectRatio = VideoAspectRatio.Stretch;
Screen.targetTexture = VideoTexture;

VideoRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", VideoTexture);
VideoRenderer.material.SetTexture("_EmissionMap", VideoTexture);
```

where `Clip` is a provided `VideoClip`. I'm aware that I am setting it to "Clamp", but the other options do exactly what they say and ignore the `VideoPlayer`'s "Stretch" value. It should be noted that the plane I am trying to display the video on has ~2x the width/height of the video (as seen in the screenshot).**

I'm sort of assuming that I have the relationship between `VideoPlayer.aspectRatio` and `RenderTexture.wrapMode` backwards, and that if the `RenderTexture` size is larger than the `VideoClip` dimensions it will stretch the video to fit the `RenderTexture` size... but how can I set the width/height of the `RenderTexture` to the pixel size of the plane? (the `Screen.transform.localScale.[x/z]` isn't pixels... so how could I get that value?)

**EDIT:** Using that `VideoClip` that I know the dimensions of and hardcoding the `RenderTexture` in my code snippet above to 2*w/h, I'm still getting the same "Clamp" behaviour... so I don't know what I'm missing.

** I have tried setting the `VideoPlayer` to "Material Override", and it works properly, but that requires lighting (hence mentioned above), and I want to do this 'properly' with Albedo/Emission, so lighting doesn't need to be implemented for every video I do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've hit a bit of a wall! (I've tried searching for answers, but have only found unanswered questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751087/unity-videoplayer-not-rendering-video-correctly-to-texture)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparing SO the many expletives I used when I discovered this... it was the tiling on the `Material` assigned to the plane.